# How can I connect a variable value to a slider?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, slider, swiftui

I am trying to insert a value that continuously changes into a slider. I want to see the slider move on its own as this value changes.

I have a slider structure set up and I tried inserting that value I want in it but it is not moving. I know that my variable value is changing as I want it to.

```
struct SliderCounter : View {

    @State var timer1 : Float

    var body: some View {
        return Slider(value: $timer1, in : 0...100, step:1)
        .padding()

    }
}

SliderCounter(timer1: Float(changingValue))
```

I am calling this from another file but the slider is only showing up and not moving as the value changes

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `SliderCounter` as a reusable view, you need to user `@Binding` as this reusable view does not own the data.

Comment: so where exactly would `@Binding` go? I am new to this so thank you for the extra clarification.

Comment: in your reusable view.

Comment: `@State` should be `@Binding`